# Validating Today's Sum

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-calendar, validation

I have a column indicating how many tokens are used for an event. The daily threshold is 42, and a user is not allowed to exceed that limit. What validation formula would I use to return "You've exceeded the daily limit" when they try to enter in an event that will cause tokens to be greater than 42.

I've tried this:

```
=IF((SUM(TODAY[NO. OF TOKENS])<42,"OK","Not OK")
```

But that won't let me put in any number of tokens, even if it's less than 42.

Thanks for the help!